# FTP server use single port to serve all clients ? how does it differentiate data for each client?

Tags: ftp

A server, say for example an FTP server is listening on a port 21. Multiple clients can connect to it simultaneously and get ftp services asynchronously without being blocked.

My assumption is that the server has a separate thread to  handle each client request. (Question: Does the new thread start negotiating new port with this client or continue using the same port (21) for data exchange ?)

my understanding is that the server uses a single port (21) to serve all the clients, including new connection requests.

if that is the case how does the server using a single port differentiates between clients and how does it delegate relevant data for each relevant thread ?

Answer (score 0):

The same was as any other TCP/IP server.

Each client have a unique IP address and/or a port number. 
The combination of client address and port and server address and port creates a virtual channel. The channel is used to exchange data between client and server software running on different machines. This is typically built into OS. The client and server software does not have to handle it specifically.